# 'Foreign' characters lost when they're at the final position in a list

Tags: python, encoding

I have a simple Python (2.7.10) program like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

with open("test.txt") as f:
    input = f.readlines()

for i in input:
    l = list(i)
    mystring = ""
    for j in l:
        mystring += j
        print mystring, '\n',
```

The text file, 'test.txt', contains this:

```
AAAÖÖAAA
```

When I run the code however, each time 'Ö' is at the end of mystring, it's being output as '?', like this:

```
A 
AA 
AAA 
AAA? 
AAAÖ 
AAAÖ? 
AAAÖÖ 
AAAÖÖA 
AAAÖÖAA 
AAAÖÖAAA 
AAAÖÖAAA
```

If I run the code on Python 3 instead (having to change the print statement to 
'`print (mystring),`'), the output is correct:

```
A
AA
AAA
AAAÖ
AAAÖÖ
AAAÖÖA
AAAÖÖAA
AAAÖÖAAA
AAAÖÖAAA
```

Does anybody know why this is happening and how to fix it? I've tried googling but haven't really found anything.

Comment: You may find this article helpful: [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are printing [*UTF-8 bytes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

UTF-8 is a variable-byte encoding; it'll use anywhere between 1 and 4 bytes to encode a given Unicode codepoint. The `Ö` is encoded to *two* bytes in UTF-8, while the letter `A` requires only one:

```
>>> u'Ö'.encode('utf8')
'\xc3\x96'
>>> u'A'.encode('utf8')
'A'
```

Printing just the first byte (hexadecimal C3) is not valid UTF-8 output, so your *terminal* uses a `?` to indicate it cannot decode the data you printed. On my Mac terminal, the [U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER `�`](https://codepoints.net/U+FFFD) character is printed in that case:

```
>>> print u'Ö'.encode('utf8')
Ö
>>> print u'Ö'.encode('utf8')[0]
�
>>> print u'Ö'.encode('utf8')[1]
�
```

If you first decode your data to a `unicode` object, you can iterate over *codepoints* rather than over bytes:

```
for i in input:
    l = list(i.decode('utf8'))
```

Note that you don't have to call `list()` on the object just to iterate. Looping over a string already gives you individual characters.

You could also open the file with [`io.open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open); this gives you a file object that gives you `unicode` objects by default when reading, provided you tell it what codec to use:

```
import io

with io.open("test.txt", encoding='utf8') as f:
    input = f.readlines()
```

Comment: `io.open()` will use the system encoding if no `encoding` is provided

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini: it'll default to the result of calling [`locale.getpreferredencoding()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding), yes. It is rarely a good idea to rely on the default, however. In Windows, for example, it'll be an 8-bit codepage.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to fix the problem for Python 2.

Instead of opening the file with `open()`...

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
    input = f.readlines()
```

... use [`io.open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open):

```
import io

with codecs.open('/tmp/b') as f:
    input = f.readlines()
```

`io.open()` has the same behavior as Python 3's `open()` builtin.

Comment: I'd use `io.open()`; `codecs` file I/O handling has several shortcomings and bugs that `io` improves on.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: thanks, didn't know that `io` was available in Python 2.